# Removing DefaultBloomKernel.uexp file?

Tags: unreal-4

My friend is using Unreal Engine 4 v17. His problem is that when he exports to Android, the game is over 100mb in size. He's not using materials or importing anything. He found a (probably) useless file called "DefaultBloomKernel.uexp" and wants to remove it. How can that be done?

Comment: first result on google : https://forums.unrealengine.com/showthread.php?145968-DefaultBloomKernel-uexp-What-is-it-and-is-there-any-way-to-reduce-its-size

Comment: I read this article before. This is old version of unreal. In v17 this issue still now solved. this is why i'm asking. Even if you tried to export blank "empty game" to android you will see this file ?